# Integral of the Von karman equation

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation

What is the result of this integral, and how can I proceed:

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{c_{1} \over\left(1 + c_{2}\,x^{2}\right)^{5/6}}\,
> \cos\left(x\tau\right)\,{\rm d}x\,,\qquad c_{1}, c_{2}\mbox{: positive constants.}
> $$

I see in one book that the result contains the
${\tt 2_{\rm nd}\ \mbox{type Bessel function}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related problems [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900598/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-1-infty-x-5-3-cos-leftx-1-tau-ri/900659#900659). Follow the steps

1) the integrand is even so you can integrate on the interval $(0,\infty)$

2) expand the function $\cos(x)$ in terms of its Taylor series

3) use the [beta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575361/applications-of-the-residue-theorem-to-the-evaluation-of-integrals-and-sums) to evaluate the integral and then  resum.

**Added:** Here is a closed form for a more general integral

> $$ c_1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos\left(x\tau\right)}{\left(1 + c_{2}\,x^{2}\right)^{\alpha}}}\,
> \,{\rm d}x = \frac{ c_{{1}}{c_{{2}}}^{-1/4-1/2\,\alpha}{\pi}^{3/2} \,{\tau}^{\alpha-1/2}{2}^{1/2-\alpha} }{\Gamma \left(\alpha\right) \cos \left( \pi \,\alpha  \right) }
> {{\rm I}_{1/2-\alpha}\left({\frac { {\tau}}{\sqrt {c_{{2}}}}}\right)} $$

in terms of the [modified Bessel function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) of the first kind. Pay attention for what values of $\alpha$ the above formula make sense.

Comment: if we have only x and not x^2. How can I proceed?

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: I think I gave you the steps how to solve this problem and I gave you a formula for a general case!

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal  Yes It is well answered, but I can't accept all of the two answers. I don't know why. The second question is that I suppose to have only x at the place of $x^2$. Thank you alot.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: Still you can get a solution if you replace $x^2$ by $x$.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: Try to work out the problem. I'll be with you later.

Comment: Good, I will try to do the same thing with Taylor series, and I tell you what it gives .

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: See what I added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16444/discussion-between-ahmed-abrous-and-mhenni-benghorbal).

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal The result that you gave me contains the Lommel function which tends to zero, but When we have treated the same problem with Mellin Transform, we have not find the same thing.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: What do you mean by "tends to $0$"?

Comment: When $\tau$ tends to infinity, then the Integral tends to 0, but with the Mellin Transform It is not the same result. Can I send you the development by mail?

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: Are you interested in asymptotic behavior of the integral for large $\tau$?

Comment: it's done.  Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: I'll add some material.

Comment: Why In my case of solution that I sent you, I don't have the same thing?

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: I made a small correction.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: It is $1/(1+c_2x)^{5/6}$ not $1/(1+c_2x)^{5/3}$. What you sent me is $1/(1+c_2x)^{5/3}$

Comment: I will send the other integral soon.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: It is better to post a new question for the other problem.

Comment: I think that the result is not good. I send you the detail.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: the most important thing was given to you which is the techniques! The rest is your job. However I will double check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{c_{1} \over\pars{1 + c_{2}\,x^{2}}^{5/6}}\,
\cos\pars{x\tau}\,\dd x\,,\qquad c_{1}, c_{2}\mbox{: positive constants.}}$

> \begin{align}&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{c_{1} \over\pars{1 + c_{2}\,x^{2}}^{5/6}}\,
> \cos\pars{x\tau}\,\dd x
> =2c_{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{x\verts{\tau}} \over\pars{1 + c_{2}\,x^{2}}^{5/6}}\,
> \,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={2c_{1} \over c_{2}^{5/6}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {\cos\pars{x\color{#c00000}{\verts{\tau}}}\over
> \bracks{x^{2} + \pars{\color{#c00000}{c_{2}^{-1/2}}}^{2}}^{\color{#c00000}{1/3} + 1/2}}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

With the [Bessel Function Identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_376.htm) ${\bf 9.6.25}$:
$$
{\rm K}_{\nu}\pars{xz}
={\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1/2}\pars{2z}^{\nu} \over \root{\pi}x^{\nu}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{xt} \over \pars{t^{2} + z^{2}}^{\nu + 1/2}}\,\dd t
$$
we'll have
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{x\tau} \over\pars{1 + c_{2}\,x^{2}}^{5/6}}\,
\,\dd x
={\root{\pi}\verts{\tau}^{1/3} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3 + 1/2}\pars{2/\root{c_{2}}}^{1/3}}\,
{\rm K}_{1/3}\pars{\verts{\tau}\,{1 \over \root{c_{2}}}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{c_{1} \over\pars{1 + c_{2}\,x^{2}}^{5/6}}\,
> \cos\pars{x\tau}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{c_{1}\root{\pi}\over
> \Gamma\pars{5/6}}\,\pars{\verts{\tau}\root{c_{2}} \over 2}^{1/3}
> \,{\rm K}_{1/3}\pars{\verts{\tau} \over \root{c_{2}}}}
> \end{align}

Comment: A great answer (+1)! (I know $c_1$ is irrelevant here, but shouldn't it be in the final expression?)

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks. You are right. Fixed.