# asymptotic expansion of the integral for large tau

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, asymptotics

How can I proceed to resolve this integral?

$$ c_1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos\left(x\tau\right)}{\left(1 + c_{2}\,x\right)^{\alpha}}}\,
\,{\rm d}x $$
where $c_1, c_2$ are positive constants, and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.
and what is the asymptotic expansion of the integral for large $\tau$.
Thank you.

Comment: Have a look to the accepted answer of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895436/integral-of-the-von-karman-equation (second addendum)

Comment: @Dmoreno It is the same OP that accepted it. I am not sure if you (OP) was not sure about the answer? :/

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Maybe he's looking for a more detailed explanation. He should show us, by the way, what his efforts on the resolution of the problem are.

Comment: I am searching an explanation or a way to resolve the problem :) and not a result.

Comment: Is it ok like that :)  ?

Comment: No because at first, the equation is not even and after that I have not found the table which gives the usual integral. So It takes work to get the good way to resolve this integral.

Comment: I have done the change of variable $t=1+c2*x$ after that I have used the Mellin Transform, but the result is not the expected one.

Comment: My bad! I totally misread the integral! Sorry

Comment: What is $\tau$? (Constant, Variable etc)

Comment: $\tau$ can be considered as a constant for integration.

Comment: I just [evaluated something similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/895536/85343).