# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{-5/3} \cos\left((x-1) \tau\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, maple, hypergeometric-function

I would like to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{-5/3} \cos\left((x-1) \tau\right) dx$$
I get the Integral by Maple and it gives the Lommel function. After that, I will search an asymptotic as $\tau$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Related problems [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895436/integral-of-the-von-karman-equation/895440#895440). Here is how you can evaluate the integral. Making the change of variables $u=x-1$ gives

> $$I =  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\tau u)}{(1+u)^{5/3}}du. $$

Using the Taylor series of $\cos(\tau u)$ we get

> $$ I = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k \tau^{2k} }{(2k)!}  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{2k}}{(1+u)^{5/3}}du. $$

Making the change of variables $1+u=\frac{1}{t}$ casts the above integral in terms of the $\beta$ function and then resum the series and the result will follow in terms of [Lommel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lommel_function).

> $$I= \frac{3}{2}-{\frac {27}{8}}\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {27}{8}}\,{x}^{\frac{7}{6}}s_{\frac{11}{6},\frac{1}{2}}( x ). $$

Another form for the solution can be obtained in terms of the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

> $$ I = \frac{3}{2} {}_1F_2\left( 1;\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{3}; -\frac{x^4}{4} \right) . $$

Comment: It's not what Maple gives me. So where is the problem :)

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: Which answer are you talking about?

Comment: I talk about the Integral here. I have found the same thing by calculus as you have done but with Maple it is not the same thing. Can you try please. Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: These solution are equivalent to the ones which are given by Maple. You can use them instead. You should evaluate the integral with the beta function and resum and you will get the first answer.

Comment: Yes but the plot of the two functions are not the same. I have tried to get the Integral directly by Maple. Can you type the Integral directly on Maple. I see also that with Maple the Integral goes to zero as tau goes to infinity. It's not the same thing as by calculus.

Comment: I see also that with the beta function B(x,y), x and y are positive values, I think that the problem is here. If you want I send you the development

Comment: I found the difference. In the development we have done, it is LommelS2 and not LommelS1.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: in the above two answers replace $x$ by $\tau$.

Comment: Yes but the problem is not here. With Maple when I do the sum like mentionned I obtain LommelS1 function but When I calculate the Integral with Maple it gives LommelS2 instead.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: I do not know what is wrong with Maple's answer! Use the results I gave you which I derived using my own techniques as you see. By the way, Have you tried Mathematica to evaluate the integral?

Comment: No but I will try to do it :). When you write s, what function you mean. because I find two Lommel functions here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LommelFunction.html

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: I already put a link. It is LommelS1.